# VueJS 2 - Mode not working on rendered v-for list

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to use the `<transition>` tag on a v-for rendered list, and it mostly works, except `mode='out-in'` isn't working. There's 10 items in the list.

The transition will work, but it loads the second element before the first one has finished it's transition.

```
div(v-for='(q, key, index) in questions')
    transition-group(
       v-bind:name='transChg'
       mode='out-in'
       tag='p'
    )

   div.question.col-xs-12(v-if='question == index' key='q')
        div
            | Question {{ question + 1 }}
            hr

            div.quest-text
            | {{ q.questText }}

                div.row.text-center
                    div.col-xs-6.answer-outer
                        div.answer-tile(
                            @click='[selectAns(0),selAns = q.answersText[0].Movie]'
                            v-bind:class='{ selectedAns1: question0 }'
                            )
                                | {{ q.answersText[0].Answer }}
```

And the CSS

```
.drop-in-enter-active {
   transition: all 3s ease;
}

.drop-in-leave-active {
   transition: all 5s cubic-bezier(1.0, 0.5, 0.8, 1.0);
}

.drop-in-enter, .drop-in-leave-to {
   transform: translateY(150px);
   opacity: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After checking the source documents again, I realized that you can't use the `mode` prop in `<transition-group>`. After rearranging the divs, I was able to use `<transition>` which let me use `mode`.